# MongoDB $text search: diacritic insensitivity + full phrase matching?

Tags: mongodb

I have in my collection, for example, `Đà Nẵng`. I want to be able to retrieve it by searching `Da Nang`, so I use $text search which is by default diacritic insensitive, and case insensitive too. Cool.

`db.cities.find({$text: {$search: '"Da Nang"'}})`

If I want to search for the full phrase, and not `Da` and `Nang` separately, I have to put it in quotes. Problem is this apparently overrides the diacritic insensitivity(I did try explicitly setting `$diacriticSensitive` to false). It only searches the exact string `Da Nang`. So how can I have it both ways?

One possibility is leaving it unquoted and instead sorting by textScore, but I don't have much faith in the reliability of that method.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who happens to have this problem, the solution is to use Collation

`db.cities.find({'name':'Da Nang'}).collation({locale: 'en_US', strength: 1 })`

https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/collation/